# Strip our a sub string based on a vlookup on anther sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup

Full disclosure, I am novice when it comes to excel formulas but have experience with programing so I will first explain the logic I need before diving into syntax.

What I would like is to be able to have 2 sheets in an excel workbook. Sheet 1 is the where the data is. There is a column that follows a very condulated naming convention however their is a base name to it. It is this value that i would like to pull out an populate a second column with.

Sheet 2 will simply be a place to input base names for the function to reference.

Each FullName will start with a basename. So i would like to do something like : `If Sheet1.FullName StartsWith Anything in Sheet2.Basenames Then Sheet1.BaseName = Sheet2.Bsename`

A c# script, albeit unpolished, would look something like:

```
public class Sheet1Row
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}

public class Sheet2Row
{
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
{
    List<Sheet1Row> sheet1 = new List<Sheet1Row>(){
        //row1
        //row2
        //row3
    };

    List<Sheet2Row> baseNames = new List<Sheet2Row>()
    {
        //BaseName1
        //BaseName2
        //BaseName3
    };

    foreach(var row in sheet1)
    {
        foreach(var name in baseNames)
        {
            if (row.FullName.StartsWith(name))
            {
                row.BaseName = name;
            }
        }

    }

    }
}
```

I'm thinking something like a substring to search on a vlookup?

**Sample Data**

Data

[image]

Base name Lookup

[image]

Comment: So is there always a space between the base name to be extracted and the rest of the full name?

Comment: You are right! I had intended on including a sample. The main thing to note is that the Full Name will always start with the base name. Everything after that is a result of a few things that are not very reliable in terms of programming.

Comment: Yes, their will always be a space

Comment: Are there ever spaces in the base name?

Comment: Yes, there could be a space in the base name. And it can be multiple words. `Quick Brown Fox` would be an acceptable base name.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to simplify this, but here's one approach:

If your Base Name list is on Sheet2, cells `A1:A5`:

[image]

Then in Sheet1 use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,A2)),ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5)))
```

[image]